# How to package an assembly in Maven by moving resources out of the war?

Tags: maven, war, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-war-plugin

Our project is set up to package a WAR and this works great for local development:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>package-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
        ...
```

Included in this war, is a mapper file and logback file used by the application, which lives under: `src/main/resources/logback.xml` and `/src/main/resources/mappers/our-mapper.xml`.

In building the war, these files get sent where we expect and want them to be, under `our.war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml` and `our.war/WEB-INF/classes/mappers/our-mapper.xml`

When we package our assembly to hand off for deployment, we need to have these files separated out of the war, which we do using our assembly descriptor:

```xml
<assembly>
    <formats>
        <format>tar.gz</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>target/${build.finalName}.war</source>
            <outputDirectory>${tomcat-instance}/webapps</outputDirectory>
        </file>
        <file>
            <source>src/main/resources/logback.xml</source>
            <outputDirectory>${tomcat-instance}/resources/</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/resources/mapper</directory>
            <outputDirectory>${tomcat-instance}/resources/mapper/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

And configured in Maven with:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/resources/our-assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This constructs the assembly, but my concern is the `logback.xml` and `mappers/our-mapper.xml` files are still contained inside the `war` which is contained inside the `assembly.tar.gz`.

Is it possible to keep the configuration where the war *outside* the assembly contains the `.xml` files as it already does, but also have the war that goes *inside* the assembled `.tar.gz` assembly exclude these same files so they don't appear twice on the classpath?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably found a solution or workaround to this problem now - however, I was intrigued to know whether this was possible so I created a small test project with the same file structure as you described.

I managed to get this project to build out the two war files - with the one outside the assembly containing the .xml files, and the one inside the assembly excluding the .xml files. I achieved this by creating an additional assembly that builds a second temporary war file which explicitly excludes the .xml files. Then the existing assembly includes this new war file, rather than the default war.

The new assembly `war-assembly.xml` looks like this:

```
<assembly>
    <id>temp</id>
    <formats>
        <format>war</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>target/${build.finalName}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/logback.xml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/mapper/*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

The existing assembly is then modified to include the new war file:

```
<assembly>
    <formats>
        <format>tar.gz</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>target/${build.finalName}-temp.war</source>
            <outputDirectory>${tomcat-instance}/webapps</outputDirectory>
            <destName>target/${build.finalName}.war</destName>
        </file>
        <file>
            <source>src/main/resources/logback.xml</source>
            <outputDirectory>${tomcat-instance}/resources/</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/resources/mapper</directory>
            <outputDirectory>${tomcat-instance}/resources/mapper/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

And then the `pom.xml` is modified to reference the new assembly before the existing assembly.

```
<descriptors>
    <descriptor>src/main/resources/war-assembly.xml</descriptor>
    <descriptor>src/main/resources/our-assembly.xml</descriptor>
</descriptors>
```

That seemed to work ok. It did leave the `-temp` war file lying around in the `target` folder which could potentially be removed to save any confusion.

Comment: Thanks.  I can see this being a potential path to choose.